# Problema al colocar y borrar elementos de select a un textarea html

Tags: jquery, html5

Quiero colocar los elementos de un select a un textarea, el código que tengo funciona bien para agregar el texto, pero el problema surge al momento de eliminar el texto del textarea, si elimino algo del mismo, no me deja volver a colocar mas texto desde el select, a continuación pongo el código que tengo.

```js
function agregar(texto){
  console.log(texto);
  $("#test1").append(texto+"\n");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <title>Problema</title>
</head>
<body>
<select name="" id="test" onchange="agregar($('#test option:selected').text())">
  <option value="1">Uno</option>
  <option value="2">Dos</option>
  <option value="3">Tres</option>
  <option value="4">Cuatro</option>
</select>
  <br/>
<textarea name="" id="test1" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

**¿Cómo podría solucionar este problema, o a que se debe esto?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bueno, yo lo resolvería de la siguiente manera:

`textarea` es un elemento de entrada de texto por lo cual no capturaría su valor con `.html()` si no con `.val()` y así mismo se lo asignaría ya que es realmente la función que le corresponde, acá te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
function agregar(texto){
  var html = $("#test1").val();
  html += texto + "\n";

  $("#test1").val(html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="test" onchange="agregar($('#test option:selected').text())">
  <option value="1">Uno</option>
  <option value="2">Dos</option>
  <option value="3">Tres</option>
  <option value="4">Cuatro</option>
</select>
  <br/>
<textarea name="" id="test1" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```